# Scraping Javascript text from web page using Python

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, web-scraping

I am currently trying to pull latitude and longitude from the TripAdvisor website from various restaurants. I was looking through the HTML of this restaurant in Hong Kong.

[Restaurant I am attempting to scrape from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1lRy.png)

In the HTML I found this:

[HTML Code with the Latitude and Longitude](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8Lnw.png)

I want to scrape the latitude and longitude from here but I can't seem to get it out when I attempt to print it. Below is my code, and any suggestion would be helpful.

```
#import libraries
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

#loop to move into the next pages. entries are in increments of 30 per page
for i in range(0, 1, 30):
    #need this here for when you want more than 30
    while i <= range:
        i = str(i)
    #url format offsets the restaurants in increments of 30 after the oa
    url1 = 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurants-g294217-oa' + i + '-Hong_Kong.html#EATERY_LIST_CONTENTS'
    r1 = requests.get(url1)
    data1 = r1.text
    soup1 = BeautifulSoup(data1, "html.parser")
    for link in soup1.findAll('a', {'property_title'}):
        #print 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g294217-' + link.get('href')
        restaurant_url = 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g294217-' + link.get('href')
        #print restaurant_url
        r2 = requests.get(restaurant_url)
        data2 = r2.text
        soup2 = BeautifulSoup(data2, "html.parser")
        for script in soup2.findAll('script', {'type', 'text/javascript', 'lat'}):
            print script.string
```

Answer (score 0):

To scrape javascript powered pages you need to use [selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bselenium%5D%20scrape).

Comment: No it's available in python 2.7